# Establish teamcity session from javascript

Tags: teamcity

Objective: 
Any domain user can view the build report in the team city irrespective of permission level to that project. To achieve this, a global service user credentials is available which had only view permission.

Is there any possibilities of using global service user credentials, skip the login page (silent login) and view the specific project build report.

Guest user login is ruled out from the option and looking for other solution. The portal is JavaScript based with the reference link to target project build report.

Answer (score 0):

- That's what [TeamCity API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildRequests) is designed for. There are plenty of
  option to work with builds.

  `Get details of a specific build: GET
  http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/<buildLocator>`
- TeamCity also lists a number of available [plugins](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/TeamCity+Plugins#TeamCityPlugins-Reporting) that depending on what you use at the back-end might provide easy integration option. For example, you can embed build status information into Confluence page using [Confluence plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.stiltsoft.confluence.extra.confluence-teamcity-plugin).